# Write to .csv file with PHP (Commas in Data Error)

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am working on a PHP statement that runs a query and then writes the data to a .csv file. The problem I am having is that some of the data I am receiving from the server has commas in the data which causes for the .csv file to enter data in the wrong place. Below I have an example of the code.

```
$sql = "Select *
From table;"

$data = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row= ("Column One, Column Two, Column Three\n");

while ($result = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row .= ("$result[columnOne], $result[columnTwo], $result[columnThree]\n");
}

$fd = fopen("./filePath.csv", "w") or die ("Error Message");
fwrite($fd, $row);
fclose($fd);
```

Column three is where the data contains commas which causes for it to write to different cells in the .csv file. Is there any solution to make the $result[columnThree] data stay in one cell even though it contains commas in it?

Comment: Use `fputcsv()` to write CSV data, not `fwrite()`. [Reference here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Yes, and use the text enclosure, or else how does an app know what commas are separators and what are data?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the values in double-quotes:

```
$row .= ('"'.$result['columnOne'].'", "'.$result['columnTwo'].'", "'.$result['columnThree'].'"\n"');
```

Instead of concatenating a string, I like to use arrays as much as possible:

```
$rawCsv = array();
while ($result = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (count($rawCsv) === 0)
        $rawCsv[] = '"'.implode('","', array_keys($result )).'"';
    $rawCsv[] = '"'.implode('","', $result ).'"';
}
$csvString = implode("\n", $rawCsv);
```

Both of these approaches will have a hard time with a different character in your data though -- the double quote. With that in mind, an even better alternative would be to use `fopen` and `fputcsv` to create your CSV data and you don't have to think about it.

If you plan to immediately offer the CSV data for download, you don't need a file at all, just dump it into the output butter:

```
ob_start();
$file_handle = fopen("php://output", 'w');
```

... if you do want to hang on to a file, then use `fopen` on the desired output file and skip the call to `ob_start`

Next, assemble your data:

```
fputcsv($file_handle, array(
    'Your',
    'headings',
    'here'
));

while ($result = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($file_handle, array(
        $result['Your'],
        $result['data'],
        $result['"here"']
    ));
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

... If you're using a file, then you're all set! If you are using the output buffer (no file used), you can grab the CSV data and send it to the browser directly:

```
$csv = ob_get_clean();
echo $csv; // should send headers first!
```

Be careful with output buffering, though, some frameworks/applications make use of it internally. If you're running in to problems with it, try using a file. If the file works, then your framework is probably already doing something with the output buffer.

**Documentation**

- RFC 4180 *Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files* - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180
- `implode` - http://php.net/function.implode
- `fopen` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- `fclose` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php
- `fputcsv` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php
- `ob_start` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
- `ob_get_clean` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: Why the output buffering? The buffer and `$csv` will be empty.  You haven't output anything.

Comment: It does when using the ouput buffer for the file handle. If you're just going to write it to a file, it would probably be better to just use a file in the file handle. I'll make a note of that in the answer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver No problem! That could have used some clarification anyway :)

Comment: @ChrisBaker Thanks so much! I tried the first option that you had listed and it didn't work. The .csv file was producing this: "\n"Content"\n"Content"\n" repeating. I have moved on to the second method that you listed and want to make sure that the $baseData variable that you listed would be the same as my $data variable. Thanks so much for the help thus far!

Comment: @ChuckMN Yes, same variable. Also, the first code example contained a typo, I fixed that, and made the examples more closely resemble your code. However, the code shown here is intended to be a little general, change as necessary to fit your use-case. The important take-away here, though, is the **concept**, and that you're much better off using fputcsv