# PHP - form results to CSV - replace commas before writing

Tags: php, csv, replace, fwrite, strip

I am trying to change / strip / replace the COMMAS from the results of a form before it is saved to a CSV file.

The basic process:

1. form filled out by a user. submit
2. result written to a CSV file  (open, write, close)
3. email to an email address. (mail: to, subject, message, headers)

I have tried the wrapping of data with "\" as described here >> [Write to .csv file with PHP (Commas in Data Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442458/write-to-csv-file-with-php-commas-in-data-error)

This is my basic form > form.php

```
<form action="thanks.php" method="post" >
    <label for="Title">Title</label>
    <select name="Title" class="form-control">
        <option value=""> - select - </option>
        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    </select>

    <label for="FirstName">First Name *</label>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="" id="FirstName">

    <label for="LastName"> Last Name *</label>
    <input name="LastName" type="text" value="" id="LastName">

    <label for="Email">Email Address *</label>
    <input name="Email" type="text" value="" id="Email">

    <label for="Comments">Comments</label>
    <textarea name="Comments" rows="2" class="form-control" id="Comments"></textarea>

    <label for="Description">Description</label>
    <textarea name="Description" rows="2" class="form-control" id="Description"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

What I have got working:

1. Collecting of filled out form data to thanks.php
2. Opening and writing to a csv file (well twice - ones a backup)
3. Sending of forms data as html to an email

---

thanks.php

```
    <?php extract ($_POST); ?>
    <?php
        $Title =        $_POST['Title'];
        $FirstName =    $_POST['FirstName'];
        $LastName =     $_POST['LastName'];
        $Email =        $_POST['Email'];
        $Description =  $_POST['Description'];
        $Comments =     $_POST['Comments'];

        $fp = fopen("thedata.csv", "a");
        $savestring =
            $arr[] = "\"".$Title."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$FirstName."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$LastName."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$Email."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$Description."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$Comments."\"".
            "\n";
        fwrite($fp, $savestring);
        fclose($fp);

        $fp = fopen("backupdata.csv", "a");
        $savestring =
            $arr[] = "\"".$Title."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$FirstName."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$LastName."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$Email."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$Description."\",".
            $arr[] = "\"".$Comments."\"".
            "\n";
        fwrite($fp, $savestring);
        fclose($fp);
    ?> 

    <?php
    {
      PRINT "<h1>Thanks for filling out the form</h1>";
    }
    $to  = "email@address.com".",";
    $subject = "Contact the client";
    $message = "
      <html><head><style>body,p,td{font-family:calibri; font-size:11pt; color: #000000}</style></head><body>
        <table cellpadding=5>
          <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>FirstName</td>
            <td>LastName</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Comments</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>$Title</td>
            <td>$FirstName</td>
            <td>$LastName</td>
            <td>$Email</td>
            <td>$Description</td>
            <td>$Comments</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         </body>
      </html>
    ";
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:email@address.com" . "\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

---

**What is NOT working...**

When I open the csv file (in excel/sheets), I noticed that people are adding commas to the description and / or comments fields... so there are extra columns automatically.

I have tried using semi-colons instead in $savestring but then it doesn't even separate into columns. Just one line, and where I put a comma in description that's where the next column comes.

So I know I need to replace the commas THEY type in with hyphens (or something else) BEFORE I write to CSV so that columns are NOT created, therefore breaking the formatting of data into extra columns.

I just can't figure out how :|

Comment: This will replace commas with semicolons `$arr[] = "\"".str_replace(",", ";", $Description)."\",".`

Comment: **GENIUS**.. although I am now getting dizzy with all the " and , ;  :).  Would you recommend I do that with all fields or just Description and Comments?

Comment: Normally with a CSV if you put your column values inside double quotes, then any commas within those will not be treated as extra column separators, and this also maintains the integrity of the data (i.e. not replacing commas the user wrote with some other character which they had not intended)